# Sorting issue in latest JQ Grid

Tags: javascript, sorting, jqgrid

I am facing issue related to sorting in jq grid ,when i enter simple text in column data in perfectly sort the data in both ascending and descending order eg

```
hello 
test
master
data
lazy
```

but when i give some sort of complex string it doesn't perform sort in a correct manner e g

```
001abc_Basic_Contract 
100xyz_Basic_Contract 
123_Basic_Contract 
234_Basic_Contract 
a_b_c_Basic_Contract 
abc_Basic_Contract 
abc001_Basic_Contract 
Basic_Contract 
Doc_1_Basic_Contract 
Doc_13_Basic_Contract 
Doc_14_Basic_Contract 
EFAIL   
EXE_Design_SG_DD 
IDCMSExcellus 
Letter_Design 
SBCv1   
SortTest_Basic_Contract 
SortTest_Basic_Contract 
TA  
Tango   
test_Basic_Contract 
xyz_Basic_Contract
```

when i give above mentioned data as column data it doesn't perform sort in correct manner.

```
  $("#grid").jqGrid({
        data:mydata,
        datatype: "local",

        height: 250,
            colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
            colModel:[

                {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
                {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'}, sortable :true},
                {name:'name',index:'name', width:100 , sorttype:'text', sortable:true  },
                {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
                {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
                {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
                {name:'note',index:'note', width:150}       
            ],
            multiselect: true,
            sortable:false,

      });
```

If i sort the above mentioned data in Microsoft Excel,it will give different sorting order.

please help me in this regard.

Comment: First of all, which version of jqGrid you use (what is the "latest JQ Grid")? Which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Why you see the included sorted strings are not in "correct manner"? jqGrid provides some customization possibilities for sorting, but the possibilities depends on the fork and the version.

Comment: currently i am using Guriddo jqGrid Js version 5.0.0 , and sorting is even not working correctly with less version using this type of data.

Comment: Why you repeat "not working correctly" without any substantiation? To define "correct" order one have to define `compare` function on strings or at least on characters. There are *many different* implementations. Someone depend on locale for example. The texts which you use contains `_` symbol. Is there are exist some **absolutely correct** statement that `_` is less (or opposite larger) then any number ('0' till `9`) or Latin character ('a' till 'z' or 'A' till 'Z')? Just try to use [Array.sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function of JavaScript with your strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly then, you need to set custom sort function with locale string compare in this case.

suppose name column has such complex string values then set sort function like,

**you can also change this function according to different sort requirement**

```js
colModel:[
            ...
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100 , sorttype:'text', sortfunc: function(a,b,d){ 
               if(d==1)
                   return a.localeCompare(b);
               else
                 return b.localeCompare(a); 
               }
           },
           ...
```

OR if you have multiple column with such values then define separate function like,

```js
colModel:[
                ...
                {name:'name',index:'name', width:100 , sorttype:'text', sortfunc: sortdata},
                ...
                {name:'name2',index:'name2', width:100 , sorttype:'text', sortfunc: sortdata}
        ]
  

function sortdata(a,b,d){  
 if(d==1)
  return a.localeCompare(b);
 else
  return b.localeCompare(a);   
 
}
```

Comment: @amighty this helped me lot

Comment: @SanjuRao:  I am glad that I could help you